# Is it possible to run a firebase function that fetches external api on a time interval?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently working on a project where i will be using firebase to save data i get from an external api.
I am wondering if it is possible to do this on an interval (like say every 2 days) and then save this data to a firestore database.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It looks like Google's Cloud Scheduler is the product designed for this use case. As the other answers indicate, there is something called Scheduled Functions, too. It says `If you want to schedule functions to run at specified times, use functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun()`. Code examples are there in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase functions, or Google Cloud Functions, run in response to events. Cloud functions are not intended to run indefinitely. So, while it may be possible technically to force the Cloud Function to stay alive, that is not the intended use. Therefore the answer is no.

You would use a persistent resource that never scales to zero (or off), e.g. a process that is designed to never turn off.

Comment: Hi Ronnie, actually with [scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) you can very well schedule functions to run at specified times, like a CRON job.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec what that features is actually doing is invoking several other cloud services behind the scenes, namely it `creates a Pub/Sub topic and uses Cloud Scheduler `. Cloud functions are intended to run in response to events.

Comment: Indeed, the combination of several GCP services allows Firebase to offer scheduled Cloud Functions, which can be configured in the Cloud Function code using Unix Crontab or App Engine syntax. This way, at specified times, the CF platform will spin-up an instance of the Cloud Function and will shut it down when all the Cloud Function work (asynchronous or not) is complete. Therefore there is no problem of infinite run and scheduled Cloud Functions perfectly cover the functional need of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

*Note that your question may be considered as too vague for Stack Overflow*.

> Is it possible to run a firebase function that fetches external api on
> a time interval?

Answer: Yes, you can use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that runs every two days and that calls the API (for example via [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)) and saves the result to a Firebase database (RTDB or Firestore).